# Icons bleeding/shadowing on the screen

Tags: display

I have a user who's icons are bleeding/shadowing on the screen:

[image]

This is an LCD monitor.  At the start of the day, it display okay, but gets worse through the day.  The display appears fine through remote control, so it is not the graphics card; it is the monitor.

They have powered it off and on, and set the auto-adjustment on the monitor controls.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it everything, or just the icons?

Comment: Everything, @soandos.  I'v restored the desktop theme to default too.

Comment: I'm inclined to say its time get get a new monitor. Deguassing may do something, may not, I have no idea.

Comment: Apparently de-gaussing only works with CRT monitors.  De-gaussing removes excess magnetic field build up I think, and LCD monitors don't need magnetic fields to align the display of cathode rays in CRTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've just tried disconnecting the VGA cable, and blowing air over the connections, which improved the display.  Looks like there was dust affecting the connections.

Comment: Does not explain why it got worse as the day goes on.

Comment: It could be a problematic connection, or a break in the cable. I've seen this on a long cable in our shop, caused by attenuated signal.

Comment: Maybe the dust was heating up...